# Fill DateTimePicker with dataGridView Click

Tags: c#

When I click on the datagridview, I want that person's date to be written to the datetimepicker on my form.

```
txtIDEmployee.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                txtNameEmployee.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txtSurnameEmployee.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                cbTitleEmployee.SelectedItem = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                dtDateEmployee.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString(););
                txtSalaryEmployee.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                txtAddressEmployee.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                txtContactEmployee.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                bool gender = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value);
```

This code is getting error :                `dtDateEmployee.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].);`

Comment: Try removing the `;` after `ToString()`

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: What does _Still not working_ mean? Do you receive the exact same error message or a different error message? How did the data get into the DataGridView? Did the user enter it? Was it loaded from a database? You may consider posting an image of your form.

Comment: I created a form application to perform Insert, Update, Delete operations. When the user enters the data from the form application, I want to send it to my database. There is no problem so far. But when the datagridview is clicked, I want that user's data to be filled into textboxes, comboboxes, etc.But it gives an error when assigning datetimepicker from datagridview. Error : System.FormatException: 'String not recognized as a valid DateTime.'